# Is it possible for my UIViewController to detect whether it is being displayed in a UIPopoverController or not?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiviewcontroller, uipopovercontroller

I would like to use one view controller for both an iPhone view and an iPad PopOverView. If the view is displayed in a popover, I would like to do some minor reformatting of the UI.

Is it possible for my UIViewController to detect whether it is being displayed in a UIPopoverController?

I've found the contentSizeForViewInPopover property, which is great for resizing the view, but I would like to remove/hide an element if the view is loaded in a PopOverView.

Comment: I have the same question, but it looks like there isn't any reliable way to do that as of iOS 5.0. So my workaround is to add a BOOL property 'popoverMode' inside the controller and set that to true whenever I use that controller inside a popover.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think it is possible. I've tried looking at the class of the parentViewController, as well as the class of the presentingViewController, and both are null. Without them providing a property on UIViewController similar to the navigationController property, it can't be done.

Answer (score 1):

you can override below method in your class and manage it with BOOL variable or some functions

```
- (CGSize)contentSizeForViewInPopover
{
    popovermode = YES;
    [self callhideMethod];
    return CGSizeMake(320, 200);
}
```

it might help you.

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be to use/create different UIViewController subclasses for each of the 2 kinds of presentation. Quite often they can share a common superclass. Here is an example:

```
@interface CMDetailsViewController : UIViewController
@end

@interface CMDetailsSinglePageViewController : CMDetailsViewController
@end

@interface CMDetailsPopoverViewController : CMDetailsViewController
@end
```

Each of these 2 classes can customise some of the behaviours defined in your base class. In your case it will be a presentation logic, which I guess is located in one of the appearance methods (like `-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated` or alternative) or `-(void)viewDidLoad`.

As you definitely know the way you're presenting the view controller: using let's say a `UINavigationController` (on the iPhone) or `UIPopoverController` (on the iPad), you can decide which one of these 2 subclasses to create.

In general that would be my default approach also when I work on a universal iOS application. System lets you to define 2 different `UIApplicationDelegates` for each platform, which means you can use appropriate `UIViewControllers` without having tons of if-else for checking the device the app was launched on.

Answer (score -1):

You could easily check if your device is an iPad or an iPhone and make your adjustments.

Use something like this

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
{
     // The device is an iPad
}
else
{
     // The device is an iPhone or iPod touch.
}
```